# showing and hiding ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, ontouch

I have a project based on [this tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer--mobile-8868) in which the user rotates a wheel and a value of a number `int days` changes according to the current position of the wheel , now i want to make another image `ImageView circle` show or hide according to the value of this number, but it throws `NullPointerException`

this is my `onTouch` event and sorry for my bad english

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // reset the touched quadrants
            for (int i = 0; i < quadrantTouched.length; i++) {
                quadrantTouched[i] = false;
            }
            allowRotating = false;
            startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
            rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
            startAngle = currentAngle;
            days = ((int) currentAngle / 12) + 1;
            String test = Integer.toString(days);
            tvnumber.setText(test);

            switch (days) {
                case 1:
                    circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    break;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            allowRotating = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

my logcat
[image]

Comment: post your logcat please

Comment: @AdrianOlar line 194 : `circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`

Comment: `circle` reference is not found

Comment: try some thing like this before Line 194 switch case `ImageView circle = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_iamgeview);`

Comment: Where is circle defined?

Comment: can you initialize circle button like @SagarPilkhwal said..

Comment: I think you missing to findViewById circle ImageView in onCreate().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to initialize the `circle` view, most likely with the `findViewById()` method

Answer (score 4):

try some thing like this before Line 194 switch case:

```
ImageView circle = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.your_iamgeview);
```

Here is your whole code:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch (event.getAction()) {

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        // reset the touched quadrants
        for (int i = 0; i < quadrantTouched.length; i++) {
            quadrantTouched[i] = false;
        }
        allowRotating = false;
        startAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        double currentAngle = getAngle(event.getX(), event.getY());
        rotateDialer((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
        startAngle = currentAngle;
        days = ((int) currentAngle / 12) + 1;
        String test = Integer.toString(days);
        tvnumber.setText(test);
        ImageView circle = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.your_iamgeview); //<-- Add this
        switch (days) {
            case 1:
                circle.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case 3:
                circle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
        }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        allowRotating = false;
        break;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Did you define circle like this;

```
ImageView circle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```